# What is complexity of checking whether a natural number is a perfect square?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, number-theory

As the title says, what is complexity of checking whether a natural number is a perfect square?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Welcome! While this is indeed a question/answer site, it would help us a lot if you indicated what you tried and where you got stuck, so we could tailor our answers to your level of expertise.

Comment: In addition to the other helpful comments, what complexity model do you want to use?  Do you want to count bit-operations?  Or do you want to treat each addition/multiplication/etc. as $O(1)$ time regardless of how big the operands are?

Comment: Did you mean to ask about the time complexity of checking whether an n-digit natural number is a perfect square?

Answer (score 2):

For a given number $n$, binary searching for the square root $\sqrt n$ solves this problem in time $O(\log n)$.

Comment: How? $\:$ (I can't think of any way to avoid having having binary search do $\hspace{1.81 in}$ $\Omega(\log(n))$ additions of $\Omega(\log(n))$-bit numbers.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I think multiplication and addition are taken to be $O(1)$ here. In which case this is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way to find (a good approximation of) the square root than the current answer (for 32-bit floating point numbers): a generalization of [fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) (whose generalization you can read more about from [this blog post](http://h14s.p5r.org/2012/09/0x5f3759df.html)) will give you the square root of a representable number. Normally, if you take the square root of a natural number you could lose some precision in floating point arithmetic of the result, but a perfect square will have its square root perfectly representable because the square root will also be an integer.

Comment: 1. This only works for 32-bit numbers floating point numbers.  2. This does not give the exact square root; it only gives an approximation.  Both limitations should be disclosed in your answer.  Also, when you are working on fixed-size inputs, asymptotic notation is inappropriate.